# LiveTemplate remove dot from start

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, live-templates

I want to edit **fbc** live template in the android studio.
I want to if I enter ctrl+space after this:

```
 someTextView.fbc   // textView or any other view
```

my code convert to this

```
 someTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.)
```

for this change my fbc template to this

```
 =($cast$) findViewById(R.id.$resId$);
```

but when I try it my code convert to this

```
 someTextView.=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.)
```

how can I remove dot from my converted code?

Comment: its not Answer but FYI https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/8261-findviewbyme